# Let $G$ be a group, $H,K$ be subgroups of $G$. Let $a,b\in G$ s.t. $Ha\subset Kb$. Prove $H$ is a subgroup of $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm just getting into group theory and I was trying to tackle this problem and despite believing to have solved it, my textbook proposes a different method of proof to mine. The problem is as follows:

Let $(G,\circ)$ be a group and $(H,\circ)$, $(K,\circ)$ two subgroups. Now let $(a,b)\in G^2$ such that $Ha\subset Kb$ where:
$$Ha=\{h\circ a, \forall h\in H\}\ \wedge\ Kb=\{k\circ b,\forall k\in K\}$$
Prove that $(H,\circ)$ is a subgroup of $(K,\circ)$

Here is my attempt at proving this statement:

Let $h,h'\in H$. Because $Ha\subset Kb,$ $\exists k,k'\in K$ such that $h\circ a=k\circ b$ and $h'\circ a=k'\circ b$. Hence we can re-write $h$ and $h'$ as:
$$h=k\circ b\circ a^{-1}\ \wedge \ h'=k'\circ b\circ a^{-1}$$
Because $(H,\circ)$ is a group, $h'^{-1}$ exists and belongs to $H$. Hence performing the operation on the two random elements $h$ and $h'^{-1}$ yields:
$$h\circ h'^{-1}=k\circ b\circ a^{-1}\circ(k'\circ b\circ a^{-1})^{-1}=k\circ k'\in K$$
$h\circ h'^{-1}\in H\Longrightarrow h\circ h'^{-1}\in K$ and we can conclude that $H\subset K$. Because $(K,\circ)$ and $(H,\circ)$ are groups and $H\subset K$, $(H,\circ)$ is a subgroup of $(K,\circ)$.

Is my proof rigorous and correct? Or is it a naïvely simple attempt at solving this problem? As always this is purely recreational.

Comment: Your proof is fine. Just make explicit that every element of $H$ can be written $ h\circ h'^{-1}$ for some $h,h'\in H$ (simply take $h=$ that element itself and $h'=e_H$).

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: Note that  the $h'=e$ part of @Anne Bauval's comment can be used to simplify your proof, because it makes $h'$ particularly simple.

Comment: @Shaun It's a relatively obscure french textbook on how to succeed in "Classe Préparatoire".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $Ha\subset Kb$

This implies: $ea=a\in Kb$, hence, exsits $k_0\in K$, such that $a=k_0 b$, then we have

$$Hk_0b\subset Kb$$

So for $\forall h\in H, \exists k\in K,$ such that $hk_0b=kb$, hence, $h=kk_0^{-1}\in K$

$$\Rightarrow H\subset K$$